# How to store opening hours semantically in NoSQL?

Tags: date, nosql, range, elasticsearch

I'm wondering what the best way would be to store opening hours and retrieving if a certain place is open right now (or to a specific time). For humans, Mo-Fr 9am-5pm, Sa 10am-2pm is fine, but how can I get a computer to understand that and query it in a NoSQL / document based database like Elasticsearch?

Comment: i think this is a case of putting structured data into the wrong type of storage repository.  Just because NoSQL is the buzzword of the day does not mean it is an appropriate solution for this problem.

Comment: This is a specific problem within a bigger context. There's no question if or if not to use NoSQL.

Comment: Why would it be so different with a NoSQL by the way? I guess you have to store the opening time and the closing time and see if the current time is in between, right?

Comment: Right. I'm just wondering if there's a smarter way, since it's new technology and should offer some benefits ;)

Answer (score 2):

FWIW: David Smiley (one of the Solr / Lucene guru's ) and I have come up with a working solution (on epaper, never implemented at least by me) in Solr. The solution could be somewhat simplified if you only require 1 -slot per day of week, which may be what you want.

http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Modeling-openinghours-using-multipoints-td4025336.html

Problem is that this is based on fairly new spatial-stuff in Solr 4 (which stuff -> read the post), which I'm pretty sure hasn't made it's way into ES yet although I might be mistaken.

No guarentees, no docs :)

A straightforward alternative, if indeed you only have 1 -slot per day of week is to have 14 dynamic-fields, representing 7 closing and 7 opening-hours and do a simple boolean-query on the correct fields.